# Why is there a shadow gap between faces?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, lighting, unity

I made a model, but the shadow appears unrealistic. I merged all vertices that were in the same position, as I believed they may have been causing the problem. Is there any possible solution that can solve the problem to make the shadow more realistic? I used Windows 3D Viewer to take a view of the shadow. There is no light added to the object. I'm making this for a Unity project.

[image: Model with shadow]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Try checking Normals by ticking *Face Orientation* under *Overlays*. Blue is facing out and Red facing inside.

Comment: Hello, I think it looks good: [link](https://imgur.com/a/wK3bjc1)

Comment: It seems this is the fault (limitation) of the Windows 3D Viewer, the issue is called "peter panning".

Comment: What blender version do you use? I tried 3.3 and it looks fine, I don't see any shading problems. On 3.5 however it crashes when attempting to open the file.